# PostgreSQL how to disable plan caching to fix my base62 hashing?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hash

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-implementation.html) i gather, that PostgreSQL somehow employs its own cache and prepares satements ahead...

This is really bad for my base62 hash values. At some point, after 2-3 tries, they start returning the same number:

```
LOG:  base62_id.val 1501145675089
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copy_article(text) line 23 at RAISE
STATEMENT:  select to_json("public"."copy_article"($1)) as value
LOG:  copied_article_id QQZCFzm | article_count 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copy_article(text) line 37 at RAISE
STATEMENT:  select to_json("public"."copy_article"($1)) as value
LOG:  base62_id.val 1501145675089
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copy_article(text) line 23 at RAISE
STATEMENT:  select to_json("public"."copy_article"($1)) as value
LOG:  copied_article_id QQZCFzm | article_count 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copy_article(text) line 37 at RAISE
STATEMENT:  select to_json("public"."copy_article"($1)) as value
LOG:  base62_id.val 1501145675089
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copy_article(text) line 23 at RAISE
STATEMENT:  select to_json("public"."copy_article"($1)) as value
LOG:  copied_article_id QQZCFzm | article_count 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copy_article(text) line 37 at RAISE
STATEMENT:  select to_json("public"."copy_article"($1)) as value
LOG:  base62_id.val 1501145675089
```

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base62_id() RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
    AS $$
DECLARE
    chars char[];
    ret varchar;
    val bigint;
BEGIN
    chars := ARRAY['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
        ,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M'
        ,'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
        ,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'
        ,'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
    val := (CEIL(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now()) * 1000))::bigint;
    RAISE LOG 'base62_id.val %', val;
    ret := '';
    IF val < 0 THEN
        val := val * -1;
    END IF;
    WHILE val != 0 LOOP
        ret := chars[(val % 62)+1] || ret;
        val := val / 62;
    END LOOP;
RETURN ret;

END;$$;
```

In theory, this should work...

Any ideas?

Edit: How i use the function:

```
        DECLARE
            copied_article_id text := base62_id();
            duplication_check int := 1;
            copied_article articles;
        BEGIN
            WHILE duplication_check IS NOT NULL LOOP
                SELECT COUNT(*) INTO duplication_check FROM articles WHERE id = copied_article_id;
            END LOOP;
        INSERT ... INTO ... SELECT ...
                    FROM
                        articles
                    WHERE
                        id = base_id;

                    SELECT * INTO copied_article FROM articles WHERE id = copied_article_id LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is pretty bogus. Plan caching has nothing to do with this outcome, the plancache doesn't care about individual function outputs.

There's at least two giant gaping bugs in the function:

- You declare it `IMMUTABLE` but you call `now()` which is *not immutable*. `IMMUTABLE` functions must return the same result for every call with the same inputs. In fact, your function must be declared `VOLATILE` if it's allowed to return a different value for each call with the same inputs.
- `now()` is `STABLE`. It actually returns the same value for each call within a transaction. So presumably using it when you want unique values makes no sense at all. I imagine you actually want `clock_timestamp()`.

The latter problem with `now()` (a.k.a. `current_timestamp`) being `STABLE` across a transaction is likely the cause for the results you report.

BTW, the function will also probably be amazingly slow implemented in plpgsql. If you can turn it into a set operation plus string_agg it might be more tolerable, but still slow.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and answering me. I think you could be onto something... Let me try it out.

Comment: This is very strange @craig-ringer it always works a couple of times until it starts to get duplicate results...